# I want to print array in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print array in ruby and rails like php

In cakephp we apply query like that

```
$result = $this->Model->find('all');
```

after that we are able to print_r apply to print the array like

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
// the another way..
pr($result); // whatever you use
```

Now i have apply query in rails like,

```
   @users = User.all
```

after that i want to print result How can i do this without loop ?
is there any way ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14392545/1438393).

Comment: in html.erb <%= @users %>

Comment: is there any way to do this in controller ? or die ?

Comment: Php is not equals to `rails`, you can't expect to use your knowledge of PHP directly in rails without learning rails, get a rails resource and study, this is an "how do I `echo` in Php" kind of question

Comment: abort(variableName.inspect)

Answer (score 3):

When you really want to *output* the users, do this in the **view**.

```
<%= @users %>
# [#<User id: 1, email: "test1@test.com">, #<User id: 2, email: "test2@test.com">, ...]
```

This will return an array of `ActiveRecord-Objects`, which is not ideal for debugging, as it is unreadable. You will have to loop the objects in one way or another to work with the data.

If you simply want to check if the retrieved data is correct, use `logger.info(@users)` in the **controller**. Then check the `log`.

This way you don't have to mess around with views and can track the problem at its source.