# Print query object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails,I'm trying to print a query object as we do `print_r` in PHP
I've seen rails console option,
printing in view by `<%= debug(@object) %>`
but didn't find any option how i can get the contents correctly of an object

Comment: `<%= debug(@object.inspect) %>`

Comment: In this question an SO user has actually posted a Ruby implementation of print_r: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491435/is-there-equivalent-for-phps-print-r-in-ruby-rails